# Searchable spinner in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, filtering, dropdown

I want to get effect similar as here:

https://github.com/michaelprimez/searchablespinner

Flutter includes a dropdown button, but can we add searching functionality to it? Where can I start?

Comment: Here where you can start [flutter_typeahead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead).

Comment: I don't mean autocomplete, I need filtering, inline inside dropdown control

Answer (score 2):

You should create a **StatefulWidget** (button for example) which its root widget is a **GestureDetector**, then **showDialog** on button tap.

Dialog should contain a **list** of items as state and a **ListView.builder()** to build items. When you search you should render items with **items.where()** to filter items.

Comment: Not exactly what I want, but similar: https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown